# back button Qualtrics to return to specific block

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I was wondering if there is a script to use which allows the respondent to click the back button and return to a specific block (for example the block where there are the instructions on how to answer a question) instead of the previous block?

Many thanks!

Elena

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way you can go back to a previous block is to use a table of contents or repeat the block in the survey flow.

If your intent to repeat instructions, there are better ways to do it such as piping the instructions into a tooltip or an expandable/collapsible div.